# meaning of different fields in URL

Tags: android, ios, http, url, get

How can we know the meaning of different fields in a url ? Consider the following url :

```
GET /adx/pand.ipad/prod.nowplaying;d1=7;;mdid=a7710a520548b17b8483b59e510503be;msa=045;OS=7.0.3;aa=0;ag=44;app=5.5.2;artist=R309367;clean=1;co=39049;comped=;dma=535;dse=0;et=2;exp=0;fam=-1;gcat=none;genre=kids;gnd=1;hhi=0;hisp=0;hours=0;iat=1;index=2;interaction=pause;l=4eanjyc4stb46;mc=0;model=iPad3%2C4;p1n=;st=OH;station=;uq=a7710a520548b17b8483b59e510503be;zip=43085;sz=250x250%2C300x250;ord=1745855840 HTTP/1.1
```

Here we see a lot of fields as below :

```
d1=7;;
mdid=a7710a520548b17b8483b59e510503be;
msa=045;
OS=7.0.3;
aa=0;
ag=44;
app=5.5.2;
artist=R309367;
clean=1;
co=39049;
comped=;
dma=535;
dse=0;
et=2;
exp=0;
fam=-1;
gcat=none;
genre=kids;
gnd=1;
hhi=0;
hisp=0;
hours=0;
iat=1;
index=2;
interaction=pause;
l=4eanjyc4stb46;
mc=0;
model=iPad3%2C4;
p1n=;
st=OH;
station=;
uq=a7710a520548b17b8483b59e510503be;
zip=43085;
sz=250x250%2C300x250;
ord=1745855840
```

While name of some fields (out of all the fields above, i am clear about only two fields ie OS & app which indicate their version) clearly indicate their meaning, i am not clear about meaning of other fields. I have following questions :

1. Can anyone tell me about the meaning of these fields ?
2. While looking at other URL's say in android, i still see even new fields in the url. How to know their meaning ? Even different fields are seen for
   different apps over different platforms. Is there a way i can
   understand the meaning of all the fields ?
3. Is there any standard specifying complete list of fields in URL ?
   Can anyone refer me some link/docs for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are unique to the URL, that is a developer just made them up and hopefully documented them. There is no standard.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does that imply that the URL fields can be unique to one APP which may not be seen in any other APP. If there is no standard, is there any way to understand the meaning of different fields say in above case or in case of well known apps over ios/android ?

Comment: Yes, they can be unique. There should be  documentation for them but it is not generally public.